# Declaração de variável com ! no final Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, variáveis, null, swift-3

Por que motivo em algumas declarações de variáveis no Swift3 é adicionado um ponto de exclamação (!)?

Por exemplo:

```
var _nome: String!
var _idade: Double!
```

O que isso acarreta de diferenças? Quando deve-se usar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem dados que são empacotados em um tipo `Optional` onde pode ter um valor ou pode não ter. Se não tiver provoca um erro de execução. Por isso você precisa verificar antes se é possível usar aquele valor. Isto é feito com o operador `!`. Para usar um valor assim sempre tem que usar a exclamação logo depois dele.

Em algumas variáveis você sabe que é para sempre ter um valor, então declara ela já com a exclamação. Desta forma não precisa mais usar a exclamação em todo uso dessa variável.

Isto serve de documentação para você evitar códigos que anulem esta variável. Mas se anular inadvertidamente, a aplicação vai quebrar se não fizer uma verificação.

Esta declaração é chamada de [Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309).

Eles tinham a faca e o queijo na mão para fazer certo e evitar o chamado [erro de 1 bilhão de dólares](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309), mas não fizeram.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Conceptual.md).